# Wordpress carousel - Bootstrap 4

Tags: php, wordpress, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm trying to make a carousel with Bootstrap 4 posts - but something is wrong.

I only get 5 posts and I do not want to - I realize it's for 'posts_per_page' => 5 - but can anyone suggest me how to make 5 posts on one slide and 5 other posts on the other slide?

My code:

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
 <!-- Carousel items -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
 <?php 

 $args = array(
  'post_type'     => 'auta',
  'posts_per_page' =>5,
);
  $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
   $count = 0;
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
  $do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

   <div class="carousel-item <?php echo ($count == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
     <div class="offset1">              
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </div> 
 </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?> <?php

    $limit_query = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($limit_query->have_posts()) :$limit_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;?>

<div class="carousel-item">
     <div class="offset1">              
     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="btn" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
   </div> 
 </div>
<?php endwhile;  wp_reset_query(); ?>

  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: you can change your slider ui to this, this is exmple of owl carousel, and you can integrate it with wordpress also.

Comment: Yes you can do that in bootstrap carousel as well, you will need to loop 5 items within carousel-item container for this. First you will need to calculate the total posts and then divide it by 5 and then do your code to resulted 5 or less than 5 posts